# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name not right when simultaneous login from 2 machines

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I've got an ASP.NET webserver with IIS 7.

My authentication code (forms authentication) is as follows on the login page:

```
            var isAuthenticated = Membership.ValidateUser(usernameTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text);
            if (isAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(usernameTextBox.Text, true);
            }
            else
            {
                var customValidator = new CustomValidator();
                customValidator.IsValid = false;
                customValidator.ErrorMessage = GetLocalResourceObject("LoginFailed.ErrorMessage").ToString();
                customValidator.ValidationGroup = "AllValidators";
                Page.Validators.Add(customValidator);
            }
```

And on another page I display the username:

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity != null &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
    {
        string authenticatedUsername = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        return "authenticatedUsername=" + authenticatedUsername;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
```

My issue is that if me and one of my colleagues login at the same time with different login names (and different accounts), the accounts are set OK (we see different items) but one of the names is set to the other logged in user.

So if I login with username `foo` and my colleague with username `bar`, we will both be logged in with our respective accounts but either I will see the user name `bar` or he will see my username `foo` on the page.

I've seen some other accounts of strange behaviour of the ASP.NET authentication and they claimed it was fixed by disabling the output cache feature. It didn't work for me.

Any help appreciated, I've got no idea how to track the issue.

Comment: Before I could give an idea, could you tell me which membership provider you are using, or alternatively paste that line from web.config.

Comment: I'm using my custom DB-backed membership provider. However that shouldn't matter as the authentication and the name is provided by ASP and not the membership provider.

Comment: can you try:

FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(usernameTextBox.Text, false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the issue was with my code. I wanted to disable caching for the page and used the following

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="1" NoStore="true" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

which seemed to work and was mostly correct.
It wasn't complete though and the full version is

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="1" NoStore="true" Location="None" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

which works.

A posteriori it's fairly obvious waht happened. Although the client won't store the page, ASP will do so for one second if the `Location` isn't set to `None`.

The documentation on MSDN was really confusing form me for that topic.